# How to set the name of crystal report columns from code behind file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have to design a report where i need to set the names of crystal report columns pragmatically from c# code as number of columns in report are fixed but there name are varying in each instance..upto now i have made simple reports in crystal report so have no idea of it..

I have tried it with making use of crystal formula but i did not get the desired result..

please guys help me to get over this issue.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please list what you have tried, data structures, etc.

Comment: @AdamKewley sir i tried with making use of crystal formula but i am not able to generate the report..

Answer (score 0):

```
As you said you have worked on crystal reports I am giving below solution if your requirement is only throguh code my solution doesn't fit you.
```

Create columns in crystal reports and while naming the columns use forumla and write the

`If else` conditions to show the headings dynamically